# What is the meaning of "you're always up to it"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of *"you're always up to it"* in this paragraph :

> Teaching is entirely different from writing. **You’re always up to it**, or more or less up to it; there’s no question of its clogging, of its not coming. It’s much less subjective, and it’s a very pleasant pursuit in itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Up to X* in this context means *ready to do X*.

The author claims, in effect, that there's no such thing as “teacher’s block” analogous to the very familiar “writer’s block”: unlike writers, who often find that they have nothing to say, teachers always (“more or less”) have the objective subject-matter and technique they need for teaching.